# QCompleter crash on Android

Tags: android, qt, qcombobox, qcompleter

I am using Qt Widget QCompleter in combination with QComboBox and the completion mode is set to QCompleter::PopupCompletion. It works fine on Windows, but app crashes while typing text in the QComboBox on Android platform. If I change the completion mode to QCompleter::InlineCompletion, then it works fine on both Windows and Android platforms.

Has anyone experienced this issue and found some solution. Please guide or suggest some other alternative. I want to run the app on Android with Popup Completion mode as it runs on windows.

Comment: You can post a bug report here: "https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa".